# Keldysh Field Theory: Self Energy Structure in RAK basis

Tags: quantum-field-theory, electrons, perturbation-theory, greens-functions

Consider the Keldysh formulation of electrons interacting with each other through the Coulomb potential. Suppose that we've switched to the RAK (**R**etarded-**A**dvanced-**K**eldysh) basis of Larkin & Ovichinnikov for the calculation of single particle Green function. Then how does one claim through the route of perturbation theory that the self energy has the same structure as the inverse of Green function matrix? I'm guessing there should be a way to see it directly through perturbative calculations instead of guessing the same from the Dyson equation. Furthermore, is this true to every order in perturbation theory?

(If there is a general abstract way to explain the same such that it applies to fermions/bosons and any reasonable action, I'd greatly appreciate that too.)